# Problem extracting text with XWPFWordExtractor

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, docx

I have a Java application with this dependency

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
     <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

and this piece of code

```
 XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(new XWPFDocument(inputStream));
 return extractor.getText();
```

I'm trying to extract from a word document (.docx) all the text inside.
The text is extracted, but if for example there is a text box inside the document, this is ignored and therefore also the text inside.

How can I do to extract the entire text? Including text boxes and if so other possible elements that can contain text?

Comment: Did you try with Apache Tika?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problemu by using Apache Tika.

```
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
parser.parse(inputStream, handler, metadata);
return handler.toString();
```